# How to binding RadioButton with DataGridTextColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, radio-button, ischecked

I use WPF (C #).

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" IsReadOnly="{Binding}" >
    </DataGridTextColumn>

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" IsReadOnly="{Binding}" >
    </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>               

<GroupBox>
  <StackPanel>
      <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding}" Content="Col1 IsReadOnlyFalse, Col2 IsReadOnlyTrue"/>
      <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding}" Content="Col1 IsReadOnlyTrue, Col2 IsReadOnlyFalse"/>
  </StackPanel>                                               
</GroupBox>
```

Please tell me, **how to binding** **IsChecked**(RadioButton) with **IsReadOnly**(DataGridTextColumn)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***DataGridTextColumns doesn't lie in same Visual tree as that of DataGrid*** so simple binding with **`ElementName`** won't work here.

In case you are using WPF 4.0 or higher you can use [**x:Reference**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380(v=vs.110).aspx) to bind with radio buttons like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsCollection}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1"
                            IsReadOnly="{Binding IsChecked,
                                         Source={x:Reference DisableColumn1}}" >
        </DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2"
                            IsReadOnly="{Binding IsChecked,
                                         Source={x:Reference DisableColumn2}}" >
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<GroupBox>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton x:Name="DisableColumn2"
                     Content="Col1 IsReadOnlyFalse, Col2 IsReadOnlyTrue"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="DisableColumn1"
                     Content="Col1 IsReadOnlyTrue, Col2 IsReadOnlyFalse"/>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Set **`x:Name`** on radio buttons and bind with it using **`x:Reference`**.

Comment: When using {x:Reference <controlname>} in the Target of a WPF Label, Visual Studio throws an InvalidOperationException exception with message "Service provider is missing the INameResolver service." Please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: You must be getting the designer error only. This is already known bug in WPF. However, there is a workaround in case you want designer to be shown described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/159cd39a-0397-48bd-a5d7-cf3cef1a90e8/service-provider-is-missing-the-inameresolver-service?forum=wpf). Also this question might be of your interest to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392162/bind-visibility-to-checkable-menu-item-shows-error-service-provider-is-missing.